# how can I remove the customer tab at admin side please have a look in attachment https://prnt.sc/s76tjx

Tags: magento2, customer, admin-panel

how can I remove the customer tab at admin side please have a look in attachment https://prnt.sc/s76tjx
I want to remove the billing agreement tab but not able to remove can someone help me

here is a code

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_edit_tab_view">
    <referenceBlock name="customer.billing.agreement.grid" remove="true" /> <!-- Not working -->
    <referenceBlock name="billing" remove="true" /> <!-- Not working -->
    <referenceBlock name="billing-agreement" remove="true" /> <!-- Not working -->
</referenceBlock>
```

and also for this 
https://prnt.sc/s7cbiv

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments but in my case, this worked for me

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_edit_tab_agreements" remove="true" />
```